# Spring boot, how to reconfigure http-security

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot, spring-security

In Spring Boot with spring-boot-starter-security the HTTP security is automatically configured. I would like to configure the `HttpSecurity` object *after* Spring Boot has auto-configured it, i.e making little tweaks to the default configuration without having to reconfigure the whole object. How to do this in Spring Boot?

Comment: What version of Spring Boot do you use?

Answer (score 1):

One way to tweak the spring-boot security configuration is through [properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html), which by default are:

```
# ----------------------------------------
# SECURITY PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------
# SECURITY (SecurityProperties)
spring.security.filter.order=-100 # Security filter chain order.
spring.security.filter.dispatcher-types=async,error,request # Security filter chain dispatcher types.
spring.security.user.name=user # Default user name.
spring.security.user.password= # Password for the default user name.
spring.security.user.roles= # Granted roles for the default user name.

# SECURITY OAUTH2 CLIENT (OAuth2ClientProperties)
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.*= # OAuth provider details.
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.*= # OAuth client registrations.
```

If the properties does not offer enough flexibility you can extend [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) and override the configure method as shown [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Security-2.0). Example from the [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/helloworld-boot.html#securing-the-application):

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/index").permitAll()       
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")            
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login-error");    
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

*This will surpass the auto configured spring-boot security, effectively overriding it with whatever configuration is supplied.*

Comment: That's the way you tweak Spring Security's default, right. But is not the way to tweak Spring Boot's security autoconfiguration.

Comment: Yes, this will surpass the auto configured spring-boot security, effectively overriding it with whatever configuration the user have supplied.

Comment: So your answer is no, it is not possible to make *little tweaks to the default configuration without having to reconfigure the whole object*? You should add, that your answer is for Spring Boot 2, because for Spring Boot 1.5 it is not correct.

Comment: If the person didn't bother to point out the spring-boot version, I assume it's the latest. Also if you're not happy with this answer feel free to write a new one.

Comment: of course you can only change details by calling first "super.configure(...)" and then only changing the parts you need.